# How to apply Angular2 (rc.4) animations on location change with ngrx/router

Tags: typescript, angular, ng-animate, ngrx

***DISCLAIMER*** - Please note I know I am being vague and pretty high level here but I am currently without a clue on what I need to do....

I'm working with or should I say I'm trying to learn Angular2 and I really want to use the new Animation API that was provided in release candidate 3/4. The documentation is here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html

Now, it all seems pretty straight forward but I want to apply a CSS transition when we change the application url (navigate to a child view) however I am unsure how I would capture the location change event in my main.ts component or any component where I wish to add the `animations` property. The example given by the documentation uses the `@triggerName` syntax to apply or toggle the animation, but I am unsure if this is applicable when wishing to animate page transitions.

so if this was my `main.html`:

```
<my-app>
    <div class="nav">
        <a linkTo="/">Home</a>
        <a linkTo="/here">Here</a>
        <a linkTo="/there">There</a>
    </div>

    <div class="main">
        <!-- this is what I want to animate -->
        <route-view></route-view>
    </div>
</my-app>
```

and this was in my `main.ts`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    directives: [  ],
    pipes: [ ],
    templateUrl: 'src/main.html',
    // I need to capture the location change and apply a css animation
    animations: [
    // Do I need a state for this????
        state('in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
            transition('void => *', [
                style({transform: 'translateX(-100%)'}),
                animate(100)
            ]),
            transition('* => void', [
                animate(100, style({transform: 'translateX(100%)'}))
            ])
  ])
    ]
})
```

I am using @ngrx/router and I know this comes with a LocationChange class. Many thanks in advance for any advice... A link to a good tutorial would be appreciated if you know one!

This is the effect I am trying to achieve with AngularJS: https://codepen.io/schonert/pen/InAzi